# Proper handling of Category model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application has Category and App model that i want to associate

Category => has_many :apps , 
App => belong_to :category

I what user to be able to select category when creating and updating app model and it was successful done [tutorial i use](https://blog.skcript.com/implementing-categories-in-ruby-on-rails-14c2b5e77b34#.21atrm494).

The problem is when user create the app model forgetting to pass any category the application crashed (I dont know how to handle this )
[image]

The application crash with error [image]

Again, when user create the app model passing the category then decided to edit it later . . the category field wont point to the last selected category( showing the prompt "select category"), the same error happen when user opt not update the category field!

My form partial

```
<%= simple_form_for @app do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), {:prompt => "--select category--"}) %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Application title" %>
  <%= f.input :creator %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My apps_controller

```
def new
    @app = current_user.apps.build
    @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]  }
end

def create
    @app = current_user.apps.build(app_params)
    @app.category_id = params[:category_id]

    if @app.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def edit
    @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]  }

end

def update
    @app.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @app.update(app_params)
        redirect_to @app
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I accurately handle this situation?

Comment: I think you should use `f.input :category_id, collection: @categories` instead of `select_tag`, then you can skip this in controller @app.category_id = params[:category_id] and select will be populated with app's categeory_id on edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)
2. You're using `select_tag` which is out of the scope of the form object

Fix:

```
<%= simple_form_for @app do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Application title" %>
  <%= f.input :creator %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

You will need to remove the `map` in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/apps_controller.rb
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @app = current_user.apps.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end
end
```

This assumes you have a `category_id` column in your `apps` table

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to initialise @categories if create and update fails.

In create

```
if @app.save
   redirect_to root_path 
else
   #initialise @categories
   @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
   render :new
 end
```

In update

```
if @app.update(app_params)
  redirect_to @app
else
  @categories = Category.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  render :edit 
end
```